# String compare between python and serialreadline

Tags: python, arduino

I am tring to comapre string that read from serial but it always false.

```
import serial
arduino_port = "com23"
ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial(arduino_port,2000000) 

while True:
 ard_command = ArduinoSerial.readline() 
 value = (ard_command)
 myString = str(value)
 if myString == "test":
  print("if")
 else :
  print(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my arduino code ( Pull-Down Active)

```
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
int buttonState;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int i=0;
int j=77;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(2000000);
 pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  delay(100);

  if (buttonState == HIGH){
       Serial.println("test");}

  else{Serial.println(i);}

  i++;
}
```

Comment: Your Serial setting is at the absolute maximum rating (2000000). Try a more 'decent' setting, like 9600 or 115200. You can also try `Serial.print` instead of `Serial.println`

Answer (score 0):

Some of your casting are not needed, you can cast your readline method directly. Could you check the following implementation? It should work but if it fails, please share the output.

```
while True:
    myString = str(ArduinoSerial.readline())
    if myString == "test":
        print("if")
    else :
        print(myString)
```

Comment: Could you share the output? I am interesting in value of `myString` variable.

Comment: thank you. it always in else loop ,print(myString). I tried to print length of myString when arduino sent "test", it show "6". I don't know why.

Comment: It is 6 because you use the `println` which put `\n` to end of line and if you count the characters then you will see it is 6.